# Judging function based on its first and second derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I wish somebody could help me with this.

Let $f$ be a twice differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$. Given that $f′′(x)>0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then which of the following is true?

1.$f(x)=0$ has exactly two solutions on $\mathbb{R}$.

2.$f(x)=0$ has a positive solution if $f(0)=0$ and $f′(0)=0$.

3.$f(x)=0$ has no positive solution if $f(0)=0$ and $f′(0)>0$.

4.$f(x)=0$ has no positive solution if $f(0)=0$ and $f′(0)<0$.

Similar questions have already been discussed at the following links, but due to low reputation, I couldn't comment there.

[Let $f$ be a twice differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$. Given that $f''(x)>0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.Then which is true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367059/let-f-be-a-twice-differentiable-function-on-mathbbr-given-that-fx0)

[show that f(x)=0 has no positive solution if f(0)=0](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424664/show-that-fx-0-has-no-positive-solution-if-f0-0)

Now, I get that the answer to this question is (3). But I want to know what will its solution be. Will it be one -ve solution and one zero solution?

And if we believe conditions of (2) to be true, then will there be just one solution, $x=0$? Thereby disproving (1)?

And if we believe conditions of (4) to be true, then will there be two solutions, one zero and one +ve?

Comment: My advice is to try drawing out counterexamples, and if you cannot try to give a proof why you cannot. The protypical example of a function with $f′′(x)>0$ is an upward pointing parabola such as $x^2$

Comment: @PVAL There are strictly decreasing functions with positive second derivative - $f(x)=e^{-x}$ will do, for example.

Comment: @MarkBennet, it's still a useful example. In fact for all the false statements in this question, an upward pointing parabola works as a counter example.

Comment: @PVAL If you think about a parabola, $4$ is definitely false, but in fact it is indeterminate - there may be no positive solution.

Comment: @MarkBennet $f$ is arbitrary, any counterexample proves the statement false.

Comment: What PVAL is indicating is not to prove the correct answer, for that one need more than a parabola, but to disprove the other answers, and for that, the parabola works fine. It may not be the finest way of doing math, but works very well for multiple choice questions like these.

Comment: @PVAL- f(x)=x^2 only disproves (1) and (2), It never supports (3) and (4), because f'(0)=0 here and not +ve/-ve as required by (3)/(4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked about the behaviour of the function, rather than just the struct answer to each question. So here are some notes.

Let's take the two model functions suggested in the comments the parabola $x^2$ and the decreasing exponential $e^{-x}$. Note also that $e^x$ is an increasing function with positive second derivative. If $f'(x)$ has a zero (it can only have one, because it is an increasing function) we definitely have some kind of $U$ shape. The exponential cases represent cases where the derivative always has the same sign. For negative derivative, the function is strictly decreasing. For positive derivative it is strictly increasing.

Q1: Thinking of a parabola, $f(x)=x^2-1$ has two solutions, $f(x)=x^2$ has one solution and $f(x)=x^2+1$ has no solutions.

Thinking of a decreasing exponential curve $e^{-x}$ is always positive, but $f(x)=e^{-x}-1$ is zero when $x=0$. The decreasing exponential may give rise to no solutions, or to one.

Q2: $f'(x)=0$ is impossible in the exponential case. In the parabola case it implies that the whole curve lies above the horizontal tangent which is the $x$ axis. There can be no zero other than at $x=0$.

Q3: Whichever case we have the function is increasing at $0$ and the derivative is increasing, so there can be no zeros at positive $x$

Q4: Here a parabola type will have a positive zero as it will become increasing. It will lie above a tangent with positive gradient, which will cross the $x$-axis. But the decreasing exponential will not have a positive zero.

Comment: Then I guess the question is wrong. It should be 'Which of the following is **always** true?' Because (4) is true in some cases and false in others.

Comment: @Ramit I read the question as implying "always" or "necessarily" true. A statement which might be true is neither true nor false, but undetermined.